# ElasticSearch throws index field limit reached when trying to bulk index

Tags: elasticsearch

Im using this python code:

```
from elasticsearch import helpers, Elasticsearch
import csv

es = Elasticsearch(hosts="localhost:9200/")

with open('data.csv') as f:
    reader = csv.DictReader(f)
    helpers.bulk(es, reader, index='my-index', doc_type='my-type')
```

`data.csv` is a csv with 5004 headers and 2 million lines (`len(reader.fieldnames) = 5004`).

When I run this code I get:

```
[2018-10-30T12:20:59,448][DEBUG][o.e.a.b.TransportShardBulkAction] [my-index][3] failed to execute bulk item (index) BulkShardRequest [[my-index][3]] containing [101] requests    
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Limit of total fields [5500] in index [my-index] has been exceeded
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.checkTotalFieldsLimit(MapperService.java:580) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.internalMerge(MapperService.java:463) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
        at org.elasticsearch.index.mapper.MapperService.internalMerge(MapperService.java:355) ~[elasticsearch-6.4.2.jar:6.4.2]
    ...
```

my-index settings:

```
{
    "my-index": {
        "settings": {
            "index": {
                "mapping": {
                    "total_fields": {
                        "limit": "5500"
                    }
                },
                "number_of_shards": "5",
                "provided_name": "my-index",
                "creation_date": "1540894469635",
                "number_of_replicas": "1",
                "uuid": "wl1k8NZRR7GUwfMCgwpPMQ",
                "version": {
                    "created": "6040299"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I really dont understand this, it seems like everything is in place and should be working.

Comment: Check your index mapping `GET my-index/_mapping` and see the number of fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're encountering default ES ["mapping explosion" protection.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping.html#mapping-limit-settings)

Seems that you already know the settings to look into, as you have limit of 5500 instead of default 1000. Could you please check if your mapping in index actually matches your csv structure? So far it looks like superset of mapping fields and csv headers exceed 5500

Comment: I havent set a mapping to my index, since the python code has "doc_type" I thought it will configure the mapping for me from the csv headers (mapping = "scheme" for each doc right?)

Comment: ES will guess mappings from your data, but you better not go with it. One problem with it (and for some reason I believe it yours) is that for text fields ES will create analyzed field _and_ raw field, until you explicitly set mapping. If most of your data is text, probably you're facing this